# Story where humans who practice cannibalism become ghouls

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short story where ghouls were formerly people who transformed into ghouls after practicing cannibalism. I believe it was written by Lovecraft, but it might have been Vance or Dunsany, and I might be completely off about the author (though I don't think I am). It was definitely English, and an older story I read in an anthology.

I'm afraid I don't remember any other details of the story.

Comment: Hi :) Any idea when you read this? Which language you read it in? Do you remember any other details about the story (setting, main character etc)? These things can be dead hard to remember, but they'd all make it easier to look for (and most likely stop downvotes)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The archetype Lovecraftian Ghoul story is **"Pickman's Model"** where a painter of ultra realistic Ghouls appears to be taking his inspiration from something more pragmatic than imagination.

Pickman shows up again in **The Dream Quest of Unknown Kadath"** living with the ghouls in a cameo role.

In **"The Lurking Fear"** an entire family of inbred, shunned folk descend into ghoulish monsters, although he does not call them such.  Lovecraft often used the "body shape follows moral character" trope to populate his stories with horrors.

Comment: The Lurking Fear! Thank you.